# The element type "item" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</item>"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

array.xml giving me error **The element type "item" must be terminated by the matching end-tag ""** Unable to find which tag is not terminated by matching end tag .

```
         <item>apples </item>
 <item>apricot</item>
 <item>avocado </item>

 <item>banana</item>
 <item>blackberry</item>
 <item>blueberry </item>

 <item>cantaloupe</item>
 <item>casaba melon</item> 
 <item>charentais </item>
 <item>cherry </item>
 <item>clementine</item>

 <item>damsons</item>
 <item>dates</item> 
 <item>durian</item> 

 <item>eggplant</item>

 <item>figs</item> 
 <item>fresh orange </item>

 <item>galia melon</item>
 <item>golden watermelon</item>
 <item>gooseberry</item>
<item>grapefruit </item>
 <item>green kadota fig</item> 
 <item>guava</item>


 <item>honey dew melon</item> 
 <item>huckleberry</item>

 <item>jackfruit</item>
 <item>jamun</item>

 <item>kiwi</item>
 <item>kumquat</item>

 <item>lemon </item>
 <item>lime</item>
 <item>lychee</item>

 <item>mango</item>
 <item>musk melon</item>

 <item>nectarine </item>
 <item>peaches</item>
 <item>pear</item>
 <item>persian melon</item> 
 <item>pineapple</item>
 <item>plum</item> 
 <item>pomegranate</item>
 <item>prunes</item> 

 <item>raisin</item>
 <item>rambutan</item> 
 <item>raspberry </item>
 <item>red currant</item> 
 <item>red grapes</item>
 <item>strawberry</item>
 <item>sugar baby watermelon</item>
<item>tangerine</item> 
 <item>tiger watermelon</item>
 <item>tomato</item> 
<item>watermelon</item>
 </string-array>
```

Comment: Did you try cleaning your project, Does this appear in xml file?

Comment: yeah many time clean it up and appear in array.xml .

Comment: To quote Mr Miagi Wax <On> Wax </Off> <bsexample>example</bsexample>

Comment: @BibiTahira : hi Bibi, i think `<item>peaches> </item>` item causing problem check it

Comment: creating new array.xml solved this issue.

Answer (score 4):

After "peaches", use `&gt;` instead of `>`. This is needed by [XML standard](http://www.w3.org/XML/).

Comment: Good point.  This typo will kill the XML.  The only way to include the > is by using onof's suggestion

Comment: thank you ,i remove > this but still error see my updated post .

Answer (score 2):

It is:

```
<item>charentais <item>
```

Comment: thank you so much pointing out this tag but see my update question its giving me error .

Comment: Is it the complete file you pasted or did you forgot to insert the start tag for </string-array>?

Comment: yes start tag for </string-array> was added just create new file its working fine .

Answer (score 1):

Line number 12

```
<item>charentais <item>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<item>charentais <item>
```

close this properly like

```
<item>charentais </item>
```